# Why is my subtitle not appearing in chart?

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

Just updated chart.js to v3.8.0 and vue-chartjs to v4.1.1. I'm trying to add a subtitle to the chart and it's not appearing. I set display to true and text to a string. The subtitle object is inside the options.plugins namespace. Any ideas?

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0E9d.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKmyk.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using treeshaking and not importing and registering the subtitle plugin. Adding the import and register like so will resolve the issue:

```js
import {Chart, SubTitle} from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(SubTitle);
```

Or you can just let chart.js handle it and import and register everything like so:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```